# Java Scanner stop reading after empty line

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

I'm looking about this topic, and I have found this [Java stop reading after empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664108/java-stop-reading-after-empty-line)

I have a problem about the next code which is written in the other StackOverflow page which I referenced before:

```
while (!sc.nextLine().equals("")){
    text[i] = sc.nextLine();
    i++;        
}
```

I use something similar for test it, which is this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!scanner.nextLine().equals(""))
{
    list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

So the idea is, read some inputs (Strings) storage them into a list, and when the line is empty stop the loop.

But the result of this input:

1
2
3
4

is this output:

2
4

Of course, I was expecting that because, when you compare in the while sentence you call the nextLine method. So the next time you call it, into the while, you will call a second one, so the next line.

I'm looking if anyone knows a good way to solve this? So you are reading inputs, storage them and if the line is empty stop the loop.

Thanks you kindly.

Comment: Each call to nextLine() reads ... the next line. Store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

every time you call the nextLine()-Method the scanner effectively reads a line from the input! This means that you program jumps over every second line!

To avoid this assign the line read to a variable and then add the content of this variable to your list. For example like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")) {
    list.add(line);
}
list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```